# No more sound on my Asus Zenfone 5

Tags: audio, 9.0-pie, bugs

My Asus Zenfone 5 is beginning to have some malfunctions :

No more sound, which means :

- I can't make calls (the phone freezes to black and I can only start it up again by holding the power button)
- I can't receive calls (callers go directly to voicemail)
- I can't open the camera to take pictures or videos
- Alarms don't ring, they just vibrate
- I can't listen to music
- I can't watch videos (videos taken with my phone, on youtube, on any social media app...) : video just won't start.

I got this bug report from NewPipe, a youtube client :

### Exception

- **User Action:** play stream
- **Request:** Player error[type=ERROR_CODE_AUDIO_TRACK_INIT_FAILED] occurred while playing https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RH2v_m5dBdg
- **Content Country:** GB
- **Content Language:** en-
- **App Language:** fr_FR
- **Service:** YouTube
- **Version:** 0.25.0
- **OS:** Linux Android 9 - 28

**Crash log**

```
com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlaybackException: MediaCodecAudioRenderer error, index=1, format=Format(null, null, null, audio/raw, null, -1, null, [-1, -1, -1.0], [2, 44100]), format_supported=YES
 at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.handleMessage(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:566)
 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:198)
 at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:65)
Caused by: com.google.android.exoplayer2.audio.AudioSink$InitializationException: AudioTrack init failed 0 Config(44100, 12, 44100)
 at com.google.android.exoplayer2.audio.DefaultAudioSink$Configuration.buildAudioTrack(DefaultAudioSink.java:2110)
 at com.google.android.exoplayer2.audio.DefaultAudioSink.buildAudioTrack(DefaultAudioSink.java:1070)
 at com.google.android.exoplayer2.audio.DefaultAudioSink.buildAudioTrackWithRetry(DefaultAudioSink.java:1049)
 at com.google.android.exoplayer2.audio.DefaultAudioSink.initializeAudioTrack(DefaultAudioSink.java:846)
 at com.google.android.exoplayer2.audio.DefaultAudioSink.handleBuffer(DefaultAudioSink.java:929)
 at com.google.android.exoplayer2.audio.MediaCodecAudioRenderer.processOutputBuffer(MediaCodecAudioRenderer.java:703)
 at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.drainOutputBuffer(MediaCodecRenderer.java:1894)
 at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.render(MediaCodecRenderer.java:792)
 at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.doSomeWork(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:989)
 at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.handleMessage(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:490)
 ... 3 more
 Suppressed: com.google.android.exoplayer2.audio.AudioSink$InitializationException: AudioTrack init failed 0 Config(44100, 12, 44100)
  ... 13 more
```

---

I don't know if it's related, but I've also noticed that in the play store, when I check the the compatibility of any app with my device, it is identified as `Asus UNKNOWN_PRJ_ID`, instead of `X00QD`.

I don't know how to proceed from there, is my phone fixable ?

The last time it happened, I was able to *fix* the issue by shutting down and restarting the phone a dozen times, but this time it's not working.

Comment: There's [a GitHub issue tracker](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues/9712) related to this exception. According to them, it has something to do with low memory. Is this device running on stock ROM or custom ROM?

Comment: I am running on stock ROM, and have 4 GB of memory. Also it happened without  bluetooth activated.

Comment: Update : I think it's just that my phone is dying : it has also lost 4g capabilities (unless its very close to a tower) depite showing it has signal, SMS rarely works, accelerometer is gone... I was able to get it working again after a factory reset and countless restarts, but only for a few weeks, and the symptoms just started showing again